# How do I make a random svg inserted into another svg resize and center on the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive-design

think I have a very specific case in my work right now. Im developing UI which allows to create and customize some widgets like progress bars etc. Most of them are SVGs. Client wants icons to be customizable, so everyone wuold be able to insert random svg in it.
Here is the code of svg:

```html
<svg
  preserveAspectRatio="none"
  width="100%"
  data-value="${value}"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 463 47"
>
  <g
    id="1"
    data-name="Group 34"
    transform="translate(-54 -2059)"
    style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255); fill: rgb(50, 50, 255)"
  >
    <g
      id="Ellipse_103"
      data-name="Ellipse 103"
      transform="translate(116 2059)"
      fill="#fff"
      stroke-width="2"
      style="fill: none"
    >
      <circle cx="23.5" cy="23.5" r="23.5" stroke="none"></circle>
      <circle cx="23.5" cy="23.5" r="22.5" fill="none"></circle>
    </g>
    <path
      id="Icon_ionic-md-checkmark-circle"
      data-name="Icon ionic-md-checkmark-circle"
      d="M18,3.375A14.625,14.625,0,1,0,32.625,18,14.668,14.668,0,0,0,18,3.375ZM15,25.8,7.5,18.3l2.1-2.1L15,21.6,26.4,10.2l2.1,2.1Z"
      fill="#0000FF"
      transform="translate(121.5 2064.5)"
    ></path>
  </g>
  <g
    id="2"
    data-name="Group 35"
    transform="translate(-57 -2059)"
    style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <g
      id="Ellipse_104"
      data-name="Ellipse 104"
      fill="#fff"
      stroke-width="2"
      transform="translate(265 2059)"
      style="fill: none"
    >
      <circle cx="23.5" cy="23.5" r="23.5" stroke="none"></circle>
      <circle cx="23.5" cy="23.5" r="22.5" fill="none"></circle>
    </g>
    <path
      id="Icon_ionic-ios-unlock"
      data-name="Icon ionic-ios-unlock"
      d="M26.438,13.5H13.219V10.125a4.781,4.781,0,0,1,9.563,0h0a.984.984,0,0,0,1.969,0h0a6.75,6.75,0,1,0-13.5.091V13.5H9.563A2.821,2.821,0,0,0,6.75,16.313v13.5a2.821,2.821,0,0,0,2.813,2.813H26.438a2.821,2.821,0,0,0,2.813-2.812v-13.5A2.821,2.821,0,0,0,26.438,13.5Zm-7.453,8.775v4.837a1.008,1.008,0,0,1-.935,1.013.986.986,0,0,1-1.034-.984V22.275a2.25,2.25,0,1,1,1.969,0Z"
      fill="#0000FF"
      transform="translate(270 2064.5)"
    ></path>
  </g>
  <g
    id="3"
    data-name="Group 36"
    transform="translate(-48 -2059)"
    style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <g
      id="Ellipse_105"
      data-name="Ellipse 105"
      transform="translate(402 2059)"
      fill="#fff"
      stroke-width="2"
      style="fill: none"
    >
      <circle cx="23.5" cy="23.5" r="23.5" stroke="none"></circle>
      <circle cx="23.5" cy="23.5" r="22.5" fill="none"></circle>
    </g>
    <path
      id="Icon_ionic-ios-lock"
      data-name="Icon ionic-ios-lock"
      d="M26.438,13.5H24.75V10.216a6.75,6.75,0,1,0-13.5-.091V13.5H9.563A2.821,2.821,0,0,0,6.75,16.313v13.5a2.821,2.821,0,0,0,2.813,2.813H26.438a2.821,2.821,0,0,0,2.813-2.812v-13.5A2.821,2.821,0,0,0,26.438,13.5Zm-7.453,8.775v4.837a1.008,1.008,0,0,1-.935,1.013.986.986,0,0,1-1.034-.984V22.275a2.25,2.25,0,1,1,1.969,0Zm3.8-8.775H13.219V10.125a4.781,4.781,0,0,1,9.563,0Z"
      fill="#0000FF"
      transform="translate(407.5 2064.5)"
    ></path>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_114"
    data-name="Ellipse 3"
    transform="translate(115 11)"
    fill="rgba(39,172,255,0.5)"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 255); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_115"
    data-name="Ellipse 4"
    transform="translate(146 11)"
    fill="rgba(39,172,255,0.5)"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 255); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_116"
    data-name="Ellipse 5"
    transform="translate(177 11)"
    fill="rgba(39,172,255,0.5)"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 255); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_117"
    data-name="Ellipse 2"
    transform="translate(31 11)"
    fill="rgba(39,172,255,0.5)"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 255); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_118"
    data-name="Ellipse 1"
    transform="translate(0 11)"
    fill="rgba(39,172,255,0.5)"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 255); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_119"
    data-name="Ellipse 6"
    transform="translate(261 11)"
    fill="#fff"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_120"
    data-name="Ellipse 7"
    transform="translate(292 11)"
    fill="#fff"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_121"
    data-name="Ellipse 8"
    transform="translate(323 11)"
    fill="#fff"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_123"
    data-name="Ellipse 10"
    transform="translate(438 11)"
    fill="#fff"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
  <g
    id="Ellipse_122"
    data-name="Ellipse 9"
    transform="translate(407 11)"
    fill="#fff"
    stroke-width="1"
    style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255)"
  >
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.5" stroke="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Until now I swapped elements with ids "Icon_ionic-md-checkmark-circle", "Icon_ionic-ios-unlock" and "Icon_ionic-ios-lock" with each other and changed their transform:translate as well, and it was working,  but things get more complicated when these elements need to be replaced with random ones and to adjust their size to the parent + center them. I tried some tricks with viewbox, preserveAspectRatio etc, but nothing seems to work in the needed way.

[image]

here is an illustration showing which elements should be changed and centered and scaled to the parent.

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Instead of inserting SVG in SVG (which I don't think is possible), why don't you try to change the `src` of the image?

Comment: I tried, but I can't center it properly then, and it's sized relative to the root svg, but yes, it should probably go that way.

Comment: Then try `position` relative or absolute.

Comment: So i replaced "Icon_ionic-md-checkmark-circle" element with image tag, i see that image is properly downloaded, but i cant display it at all, tried to set different width and height, different transforms, positions etc but somethings going wrong